# R: How to divide dataframe cells values with values from a column to calculate proportion

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe (as displayed by str(dataframe)

What I need to do is divide P1 to PJ with the corresponding total mortality and replace the P1 to PJ values with the calculated proportion. I figure that I have to use some sort of apply function. But I am too new to R to go beyond that.

```
data.frame':    26 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ year          : int  1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 ...
 $ P1            : num  0.0182 0.0143 0.0138 0.0118 0.0109 ...
 $ P2            : num  0.0447 0.0348 0.0335 0.0285 0.0267 ...
 $ P3            : num  0.1128 0.0888 0.0872 0.0754 0.0718 ...
 $ P4            : num  0.278 0.274 0.307 0.296 0.296 ...
 $ P5            : num  1.67 1.42 1.42 1.23 1.19 ...
 $ PJ            : num  46.7 41.1 40.6 36.6 35.1 ...
 $ TotalMortality: num  48.8 42.9 42.5 38.3 36.7 ...
 $ GDP           : int  23895 24196 24368 25321 26372 27732 29233 30406 31847 33203 ...
```

PS. View(df) gives the following output
[View(df)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlnB5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything special. Just divide your columns with the total.

```
> xy <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012),
+                  P1 = 1:3,
+                  P2 = 4:6,
+                  PJ = 7:9,
+                  total = 4:6
+ )
> 
> xy
  year P1 P2 PJ total
1 2010  1  4  7     4
2 2011  2  5  8     5
3 2012  3  6  9     6
> xy[, 2:4] <- xy[, 2:4]/xy$total
> xy
  year   P1 P2   PJ total
1 2010 0.25  1 1.75     4
2 2011 0.40  1 1.60     5
3 2012 0.50  1 1.50     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand exactly what it is you mean by "divide P1 to PJ with the corresponding total mortality"

If you want to add new columns for the new data you could try something like this:

```
df$NewColumn <- df$P1 / df$TotalMortality
```

This would need to be repeated for each column from P1 to PJ.

If you definitely want to overwrite the data then you could do

```
df$P1 <- df$P1 / df$TotalMortality
```

again it would need to be repeated

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer by @RomanLuštrik is what you'll want.  If you are interested in an alternative approach, you could also use something like `dplyr::mutate_at` which is part of the `tidyverse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(year = 1990:1993,
            P1 = 1:4, 
            P2 = 9:12, 
            PJ = 13:16, 
            Total_Mortality = 2:5)

x %>% mutate_at(vars(P1:PJ), funs(./Total_Mortality))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    year        P1       P2       PJ Total_Mortality
#>   <int>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>           <int>
#> 1  1990 0.5000000 4.500000 6.500000               2
#> 2  1991 0.6666667 3.333333 4.666667               3
#> 3  1992 0.7500000 2.750000 3.750000               4
#> 4  1993 0.8000000 2.400000 3.200000               5
```